# Is there an AccuRev command to list all the streams?

Tags: stream, accurev

I want to get a list of all the streams, including snapshots. I can't find anything in the CLI reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command lists all the streams (be sure not to cross them):

```
accurev show streams
```

Helpful tip: You can start the GUI in debug mode and you can see what commands it runs underneath.

```
## (Tested on OS X.)
cd /Applications/AccuRev/bin/
java -Daccurev.debug.acapi -Daccurev.debug.env -classpath "oro.jar:xercesImpl.jar:xml-apis.jar:fw.jar" fw.MainApp
```

Comment: @BruceK You can thank the AccuRev support staff. They go to great lengths to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Below command will list all steam in the specific depot

```
show -p <depotname> -fxg streams
```